# If $\alpha h\neq h\alpha\in S_n$ How can $A_n\trianglelefteq S_n$ be true?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> **Question**: Show that $A_n\trianglelefteq S_n$.

**Terminology**:$S_n$ is the group of permutations, of order n and $A_n$ is the subgroup of even permutations of $S_n$.

> **Proposition**:Let $G$ be a group and $H\leq G$. Then we have
>
> $H\trianglelefteq G\iff\forall a\in G,aHa^{-1}=H$

**Proof:**

For any $\alpha\in S_n,\beta\in A_n$ we have $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\in A_n$.
Therefore $\alpha A_n\alpha^{-1}\in A_n$ which implies $A_n\trianglelefteq S_n$

The definition of normal subgroup I have is the following.

**Defintion**:

Let $G$ be a group and $H\leq G$. If $\forall a\in G,aH=Ha$

then it H is denominated a normal subgroup of $G$.

**Question:**

$S_n$ is not an abelian Group for $n>3$. By the definition $\forall a\in G,aH=Ha$ is the condition that defines the normal subgroup. However if $\alpha\in S_n$ and $h\in A_n$, it is not true that $\alpha h=h\alpha$.
How can $A_n\trianglelefteq S_n$ be true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not clear about what you are taking as the definition for a normal subgroup (you state as a proposition what many would take as a definition). You will find here several duplicates of a question asking how to prove that a subgroup of index $2$ is normal. Your question is a special case of this.

Comment: Non-abelian groups can have normal subgroups, the definition doesn't force  $\alpha h = h\alpha$, it says that for all $\alpha \in G$, we have $\alpha h \alpha^{-1} \in H$, not necessarily that $\alpha h \alpha^{-1} = h$. Also, the alternating group has index $2$ so it is normal in $S_n$, by a general argument on index 2 subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that we need $\alpha h= h \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in A_n$, just that  the entire subgroup is invariant under conjugation. When you conjugate, we can have that $h \alpha h^{-1}=\alpha^{\prime}$ and the thing to check is that $\alpha^{\prime} \in A_n$. So, this means that $\alpha A_n \alpha^{-1}=A_n$, but *as sets.*

A different way to see that it is normal, is that we can define $S_n \to \mathbb Z/ \mathbb 2 \mathbb Z$ given by $\alpha \mapsto 0$ if it decomposes into an even product of transpositions and $\alpha \mapsto 1$ if it decomposes into an odd number of permutations. Since group multiplication is equivariant with respect to parity, it follows that this is a homomorphism, and its kernel is $A_n$.

Alternatively, $A_n$ is an index $2$ subgroup, and [every index 2 subgroup is normal](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Index_2_is_Normal).